# Adding an extra category field to Joomla articles

Tags: joomla-4

I need to add an extra category field to my articles. I tried to add a SQL custom field by this SQL code:
SELECT `title` AS text FROM `jos_categories` WHERE `extension` = "com_content" and `published`=1;

The code works and shows the categories list, but when I save the article, the value of the custom field changes to the article's primary category value.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query needs to return a `value` column containing the ID of the category:

```
SELECT title as text, id as value FROM #__categories WHERE extension = "com_content" and published=1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Sharky.